# How to calculate the intersection of multiple time ranges (best meeting time)?

Tags: javascript

Given 5 different times :

```
10am - 6pm
3pm - 10pm
4pm - 7pm
5pm - 1am
3pm - 12am
```

Is there an algorithm to calculate the best time between those given times? like the mean time?

I have tried adding up each side and divided by the number of times for that side, but the problem comes when I try to calculate the `am` and `pm` for the time, so some times would have to be weighted differently right? something like military time where `10pm = 22 / 12am = 24 /` etc.

I have not coded anything for this yet, because I have been trying to figure out the bet way to go about this, but it would be programmed in JavaScript.

Edit :

```
 6pm - 9pm
 3pm - 8pm
 4pm - 7pm
 2pm - 10pm
 5pm - 11pm

 *6 + 3 + 4 + 2 + 5 = 20 / 5 = 4
 *9 + 8 + 7 + 10 + 11 = 45 / 5 = 9

 *best time range = 4pm - 9pm
```

This is an example of what I am talking about, it does not take into account the `am/pm`.

i want to find one time range that is best, given the five time ranges.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "the mean of 5 different times", what you have are time ranges, not times

Comment: try to calculate mean of time differences, e.g 10am - 6pm -> 8 hours, 3pm-10pm -> 7 hours ... then divide sum of hours by number of periods.

Comment: First you have to define what the  mean between a set of time ranges is. You could give an example (as you did) and tell us what the expected result is. Right now you just have  a poorly specified problem.

Comment: Perhaps you are trying to calculate the average *time span* or average *duration*.  You need to convert pm times into military time first; and you also need to handle the special case of 5pm to 1am differently.

Comment: Perhaps they want to calculate the intersection of these ranges?

Comment: Perhaps you want to find the intersection of the time ranges that fits the most time ranges (because some of these don't overlap at all).  So perhaps you are trying to find a "best time" for a meeting with the given availability ranges?

Comment: @KimballRobinson - ya im trying to find the 'best time' from the given times. if each of the 5 people give me a time they are available, then i want to be able to calculate the 'best time' that everyone could meet.

Comment: The best time is a relative term, what if you have no overlapping times? The mean of the time ranges is not necessarily the best time

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know the mean value of all the durations, the easiest way would be first converting to 24 hours; to account for day rollover, you could add 24 hours to the end time and then get MOD the result by 24.

```
var timeRanges = [
    [10,18],
    [15,22],
    [16,19],
    [17,1],
    [10,18]
];

var durations = timeRanges.map(function(range){
    return ((range[1] + 24) - range[0]) % 24;
});

var totalDuration = durations.reduce(function(runningTotal, current){ 
     return runningTotal + current
}, 0);

var meanDuration = totalDuration / durations.length;
```

I am not sure this is what you were looking for, but that is how I interpreted your question

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using the moment.js and moment-range.js libraries, which can quickly calculate the intersection of one or more date ranges.

https://github.com/gf3/moment-range#contains--within--overlaps--intersect--add--subtract

However, when you are trying to find the intersection of multiple time ranges, there will be cases with no solution, so you might want to find the time when most can meet (not all).   Also, realistically, people might have multiple time ranges in which they are available.

I would suggest creating a sorted array of objects that contain the date-time objects, whether it's a start or end, and who it's for.  Then, you could iterate through the array and add/remove the available people onto an array for each date-time.  If you arrive at a time that all participants are available, you find the next end time, and that's one possible meeting time--you might have multiple solutions.

```
datesToCheck = [
 { date: yourDateObj, type: 'start', who: 'Juan' },
 { date: yourDateObj, type: 'end',   who: 'Juan' },
 { date: yourDateObj, type: 'start', who: 'Juan' },
 ...
]
```

pseudocode:

```
sort datesToCheck by date property;

for (i=0, i<datesToCheck.length, i++)
  date = datesToCheck[i]
  if date.type === 'start'
    availablePeopleSet.add(date.who)
  else
    availablePeopleSet.remove(date.who)
  if availablePeopleSet.size > mostAvailableFound
    mostAvailableFound = availablePeopleSet.size
    mostAvailableTimeStart = date;
```

I will leave it to you to figure out how to get the end date in that range (hint: it might not be the next date in the list), and how to decide which time range to choose, how to store multiple viable solutions, and handle multiple time ranges for each person.